# What happens if I attribute a second instance of a class with the same variable holding an existing instance?

Tags: python, class, variables, instantiation

I'm not sure how to ask the question other than by example.

Lets say I have a class:

```
class Foo():
    pass
```

and I create an instance of it:

```
foo = Foo()
    ...
```

then,  as part of my program, I recreate the same instance with the same name (to restart a game but keeping a score total in yet another, separate class called Bar).

```
foo = Foo()
    ...
```

(I don't know the correct terminology) I havent written any code to eliminate the first instance.  Is the first instance eliminated or overwritten?  It seems to work for a small program.  If I do it many times am I going to run into trouble?

Comment: "eliminated or overwritten": both

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let me try to explain it graphically.

When you do

```
foo = Foo()
```

for the first time, you are creating an *object* of type `Foo` in memory (with `Foo()`) and, at the same time, creating a *variable* which will point to this object:

[image]

When you execute

```
foo = Foo()
```

for the second time, you are creating *another object*. Meanwhile, you are taking the *same variable* and pointing it to the new object. Of course, the variable will not point to the previous object anymore:

[image]

Now, what happens to the first object? Well, if there is *no other variable* in your program pointing to it, it is useless, since you cannot access it anymore! In this case, the object will be destroyed/freed from the memory when the interpreter runs the *garbage collector*. The garbage collector is an algorithm which will look for every object which is not accessible and will remove it. The garbage collector does not run every time, so it can take a time to the object be destroyed.

So, in your scenario, what happens is:

- The *reference* to the first object is overwritten, but the object will exist. If another variable points to it, it will not be destroyed.
- However, if there is no other variable pointing to it, the object will be eliminated at some point in the future.

Comment: Wow!  Graphical answers are the best for beginners like me!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### The basic (and probably sufficient) answer:

The variable `foo` is assigned to a new instance, which knows nothing of the former one.
It's basically going to be the same as:

```
a = 1
a = 2
```

At some point (probably sooner than later), the old instance of `foo` will be garbage collected (unless you still have references to it somewhere else).

The easy way to understand this is that the `foo` name is just a pointer that points to an actual object. If you have `foo` point at a new object, then `foo` points at a new object, period.

### A relevant detail: the Singleton pattern

There are design patterns (the `singleton` one comes to mind), which may change this behavior.

Basically, the  `Foo.__new__` classmethod is the one which decides what you're going to get when you do `Foo()`.

This method could be built so that it always return the first instance that you created, but that's sightly off-topic.

Here's a sample implementation:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

Comment: You're example is extremely unfortunate as it seems to suggest that instances obey value semantics. a = 0; b = a; a =1 is different to ca = Foo(); cb = ca; ca.v = 1

Comment: @carlosdc That is a fair point, but I wanted to use simple types as the question itself indicates that  the reader might not be extremely familiar which the topic.

Answer (score 2):

1st `foo = Foo()`:

it creates a new instance object and assigns it to `foo`, see `foo` is just a reference to the object returned by `Foo()`

2nd `foo = Foo()`

it creates a new instance object and assigns it to `foo`, and the previous instance object `Foo()` is garbage collected as there's no variable pointing to it.

example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   pass
... 
>>> 
>>> foo=Foo()  
>>> id(foo)   #foo points to an object with id 3077166220L
3077166220L
>>> foo=Foo()  #now foo points to some other object and the object with id 3077166220L is garbage collected
>>> id(foo)
3077166252L  
>>> 
>>> 
>>> temp=foo      #now both foo and temp point to same object i.e 3077166252L  
>>> foo=Foo()     #assign foo to a new object
>>> id(temp)      #temp still points 3077166252L ,so it's not garbage collected   
3077166252L 
>>> id(foo)       #it points to a new object   
3077166092L
```

Comment: +1: the key is that it is not value, it is a reference. You create a new object each time you call the constructor and you give it a name. When something you created doesn't have a name it gets garbage collected.

Comment: great detailed answer!  Thanks!

Comment: @carlosdc: You create a new object every time you call the constructor regardless of whether you "give it a name".

Comment: @martineau: yes. I was trying to explain this line: foo = Foo(), you call the constructor and you give it a name. Foo() alone would be: call the constructor. In both cases objects are created. In one case you give it a name, in the other you don't, making it a target for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points to note.

1. The name 'foo' is a variable defined in your code. In Python, the variable doesn't have a type until you assign it a value.
2. When you say `foo = Foo()` you're assigning your variable `foo` the instance of an object of type `Foo`. `Foo()` creates this instance by calling the constructor of the `Foo` class without any parameters.
3. Each call to `Foo()` creates a new instance. Hence, repeating `foo = Foo()` in your code will create multiple instances of the `Foo` class, and assign them to the variable `foo`. Earlier instances that were pointed to by the `foo` variable will no longer have a reference and can be garbage collected (assuming you didn't assign any other references to those instances in the meanwhile).

Hence, the words you use to describe your question

> create second instance of a class with the same name as the existing
>   instance

are actually not right. Because you are not creating another instance "with the same name". You are creating another instance, and assigning it to "the same variable".

Answer (score 0):

1. There's no overwrite in Python.
2. When you write `Foo()` a new instance is created (class method `__new__` and instance method `__init__` are called, in order)
3. When there's no pointer to an instance of a class, Python's Garbage Collector will eventually delete that instance (and instance method `__del__` is called on that instance)

Answer (score 0):

You end up binding a new Foo object to `foo` and your old `Foo` object will lose a reference.  If an object does not have any references, then it will be collected on the next garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The second one will override the first.  (It takes the place of the name in the module's globals dictionary, where all global variables, functions, and classes are stored).

However, the foo = Foo() that you created will continue to use the original implementation from when it was created, until you make a new foo = Foo().